# How can I loop all json data and insert into my HTML?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'd like to insert the Json data into my file.php. And so each group of them are insert into group of divs. (with the same style etc.)

I have a feeling the way I am using is not smart... better solutions are very welcome. Thanks guys.

```
    $.ajax({

    url: feedURL,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
    contentType:"application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {

        for (var i=0; i < 15; i++) {

        var date = new Date(json.posts.data[i].created_time);
        var months = ["/01/", "/02/", "/03/", "/04/", "/05/", "/06/", "/07/",
     "/08/", "/09/", "/10/", "/11/", "/12/"];



        $("#description").html(json.posts.data[i].message);
        $("#caption").html(json.posts.data[i].caption); 
        $("#expire_date").html(date.getDate() + months[date.getMonth()] + date.getFullYear()); 
        $("#fb_link").html(
            '<a href="' + json.posts.data[i].link + '">'
            + 'Total Like: ' + json.posts.data[i].likes.summary.total_count
            + ' Total Share: ' + json.posts.data[i].shares.count
            + ' View on Facebook' + '</a>'
        ); 
        $("#profile_img").html('<img src="' + json.picture.data.url + '">');
        $("#profile_name").html(json.name);
        $("#full_fb_photo").html('<img src="' + json.posts.data[i].full_picture + '">');


        }

    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the output of ``json`` inside success function??  And using same DOM element like #description will override the prev value. So even you are getting many records, only last record will be displayed.

Comment: hi @SameerK thanks for your quick response. You are exactly right the result is only showing the last one.   Output of Json are many data with keys from 0 - 14 and each data has things like time, url etc.

Comment: Show you json response.  To show all the records, you  need to build part of html inside loop and then append to some container inside your main html by using ID of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in flowing way. Uncountable date print in your loop. If I know your data format, I will give you exact way.

Try this code.

```
for (var prop in json.posts.data) {
      $("#description").html(json.posts.data[prop].message);
     // other same as
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i have figured out in this way.

```
$.ajax({

    url: feedURL,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
    contentType:"application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
 var social_list = "";
        for (i=0; i < 15; i++) {

        var date = new Date(json.posts.data[i].created_time);
        var months = ["/01/", "/02/", "/03/", "/04/", "/05/", "/06/", "/07/",
     "/08/", "/09/", "/10/", "/11/", "/12/"];

        social_list += "<div class='social_item'><div class='item'><div class='heading'>";
        social_list += "<img src='" + json.picture.data.url + "'/><span>" + json.name + "</span><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i></div>";
        social_list += "<div class='content'><p>Created on" + date.getDate() + months[date.getMonth()] + date.getFullYear() + "</p>";
        social_list += "<div><img src='" + json.posts.data[i].full_picture +  "' /></div>";
        social_list += "<p name=" + i + ">" + json.posts.data[i].message + "</p>";
        social_list += "<div><a href='" + json.posts.data[i].link + "'> Total Likes: " + json.posts.data[i].likes.summary.total_count + "Total Share: " + json.posts.data[i].shares.count + " View on Facebook </a></div>";
        social_list += "</div></div></div>"

}
        $('#social_list').html(social_list);
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Just wanted know whether there will exactly 14 records every time ?

Comment: Hi @SameerK in future, i'd like it to be showing more, and for a certain level, it loads more. However, currently I have few issues with them. 1. (It's a facebook API, and I am not sure how to have more posts, and default is 15. 2. not sure how to load more, guess using ajax again.